# Scala - Tweets subscribing - Kafka Topic and Ingest into HBase

Tags: scala, hbase, apache-kafka

I have to consume tweets from a Kafka Topic and ingest the same into HBase. The following is the code that i wrote but this is not working properly.

The main code is not calling "convert" method and hence no records are ingested into HBase table. Can someone help me please.

```
tweetskafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  println("Inside For Each RDD" )
  rdd.foreachPartition( record => {
    println("Inside For Each Partition" )
    val data = record.map(r => (r._1, r._2)).map(convert)
    })
  })

def convert(t: (String, String)) = {
    println("in convert")
    //println("first param value ", t._1)
    //println("second param value ", t._2)

  val hConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
  hConf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE,hbaseTableName)
  hConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.XXX.XXX:2181")
  hConf.set("hbase.master", "192.168.XXX.XXX:16000")
  hConf.set("hbase.rootdir","hdfs://192.168.XXX.XXX:9000/hbase")
  val today = Calendar.getInstance.getTime
  val printformat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")

  val id =  printformat.format(today)
  val p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(id))

  p.add(Bytes.toBytes("data"), Bytes.toBytes("tweet_text"),(t._2).getBytes())
  (id, p)

  val mytable = new HTable(hConf,hbaseTableName)
  mytable.put(p)
}
```

I don't want to use the current datetime as the key (t._1) and hence constructing that in my convert method.

Thanks

Bala

Comment: Are you sure you're correctly reading from tweeter? Do you see tweets coming in at all?

Comment: Yes i can see the tweets coming in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of foreachPartition, I changed it to foreach. This worked well.